# If $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ell_n}{\log n}=1$, does $n\log n\geq -C \iff (n+1)\ell_{n-1}\geq -C$ hold?

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics, harmonic-numbers

Let $\ell_n:=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{k+1}.$

It is known that $\ell_n\sim\log n.$ i.e $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ell_n}{\log n}=1.$

Then, for $C\geq 0$ it is possible that

$n\log n\geq -C \iff (n+1)\ell_{n-1}\geq -C.$

Comment: Well $-C\le 0$, so both of your inequalities are satisfied.

Comment: The question does not make much sense at present. What can be said though is that, considering the $n$th harmonic number $H_n=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac1k$ (thus, in your notations, $H_n=\ell_{n-1}$, but it is better to adopt standard notations) then $H_n=\log n+\gamma+o(1)$ where $\gamma\approx0.577$ is called the Euler-Mascheroni constant, hence $(n+1)H_n=n\log n+n\gamma+o(n)$, which implies that indeed $(n+1)H_n\geqslant n\log n$ for every $n$ large enough (meaning, for every $n\geqslant n_0$, for some $n_0$ which might actually be rather small). Is this the kind of things you have in mind?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number for all of the above and more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$n$ is a real if we suppose $l_n= \sum_{0\le k \le n} \frac1{k+1}$

So $l_n = 0$ for $n <0$, $l_n = 1$ for $n \in [0,1[$, ...

Remarks:

1/ If $C\ge 0$, $-C \le 0$

2/ $ n \ln(n) >0$ if $n > 1$.

proof:

==>
If $n> -1$, as $\ell_n \ge 0$ for all $n$, then $(n+1)\ell_{n \pm 1} \ge 0 \ge -C$.

<==
if $(n+1)l_{n\pm 1}  \ge  0$ , as $\ell_n \ge 0$ for all $n$, then $n+1 \ge 0$ and $n \ge -1$.

If we suppose $n\le 0$, then $\ell_{n\pm 1}\ge 0$ but $\ln(n)$ is not real ! and for $n \in ]0,1[$, the result  is in function of $C$ as $x\ln(x) < 0$ and have a minimum in $x=1/\exp(1)$

conclusion: if $n \gt 0$, $\forall C \ge 1/\exp(1), \quad (n\log n\geq -C) \iff ((n+1)\ell_{n \pm 1}\geq -C)$.

but the conclusion is false if $n \le 0 $ as $n\ln(n)$ does not exist or if $C <1/\exp(1)$.

Comment: Re :edit : I found your missing dollar sign .